# What does "yadda yadda" mean?

Tags: meaning

In a phrase like *the usual yadda yadda*, what does *yadda yadda* mean?
What is its origin?

> Please read, this is not the usual yadda yadda! Three things:
>
> Because the dumps are quite a bit of work for us, we’re moving to a bi-monthly schedule instead of monthly. Meaning, you can expect dumps every two months instead of every month. If you have an urgent need for more timely data than this, contact us directly, or use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, which will continue to be updated monthly. —[Creative Commons Data Dump Jan ’11](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/).
>   […]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was introduced to this phrase by [Jerry Seinfeld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seinfeld) (well, technically, [Elaine Benes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seinfeld#Main_characters)), but Wikipedia actually says that [it's older](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Yada_Yada#.22Yada_yada.22):

> The ["Yada yada"] episode is one of the most famous of the series, specifically for its focus on the phrase "yada yada". "Yadda yadda" was already a relatively common phrase before the episode aired, used notably by comedian [Lenny Bruce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenny_Bruce), among others. The phrase may have originated with the 1950s "yackety-yack", 1940s vaudeville, and earlier.

Wiktionary has [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yada_yada_yada):

> American, origin unclear, perhaps onomatopoeic of blather; perhaps adaptation of dialectal speech, perhaps from *yatata* or *yatter*. Various variant forms appear in the US 1940s–60s; for example, the 1947 American musical Allegro by Oscar Hammerstein II and Richard Rodgers contains a song called “Yatata, Yatata, Yatata,” about cocktail party chatter[...]. Popularized in the United States in the late 1990s by TV show Seinfeld[...]. Sometimes popularly attributed to Yiddish, but this is dismissed by etymologists[.]

As to the meaning, it's a (colloquial, informal) way of saying "and so on, etcetera". In your particular case, what is being implied is that when the data dumps are released, there's usually some text in rather standard wording, and if you're a regular, you begin to ignore that text after a while. But this time, the data dump is accompanied by some additional, unusual announcement (namely, "we’re moving to a bi-monthly schedule instead of monthly"), and the author warns you in advance: watch out, this is not the usual *blah-blah*, or the usual *wall of text*, so don't ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Urban Dictionary* it's a phrase that means "**and so forth**" or "**on and on**;" it usually refers to something that is a minor detail or boring and repetitive.

Answer (score -3):

This term goes WAY BACK , my Grandfather , Ronald L. Combs  , his nickname was YADDA (as in YADDA-YADDA-YADDA) which was used to say hurry up YOU TALK TO MUCH (you're long winded) You taking running on in stead of getting to the point. In his case this was back in the 1920's & was kind of a joke because he spoke very little. Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting as it is, this would have been better as a comment or the claim *This term goes WAY BACK* should have been supported by independent sources

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/419833)

Comment: I would love to believe this, but it is very difficult to corroborate it. Neither the OED nor Green's Dictionary of Slang show use earlier than the 1940s.